# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java

package mylogin;

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList; //ArrayList supports dynamic arrays that can grow as needed
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Ccompany
 */
public class Products extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Products
     */
    public Products() {
        initComponents();
        show_Products_in_Jtable(); // EMFANIZEI TA PRODUCTS STON PINAKA 
    }
    //connection to sqlserver 
    String driver ="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1435;databaseName=supermarket";
    String user ="sa";
    String pass ="sql!123";

    //connection
    public Connection getConnection()
    {
        Connection con;
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con= DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            return con;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
    public ArrayList<Update_del_insert_products> getuserList()
    {
        ArrayList <Update_del_insert_products> proList =new ArrayList <Update_del_insert_products> ();
        Connection connection =getConnection();

        String query ="SELECT * FROM Product";
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;
        try{
            st = connection.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            Update_del_insert_products  update_del_insert_products ;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                update_del_insert_products = new Update_del_insert_products (rs.getString("Pro_Id"),rs.getString("Pro_Name"),rs.getString("Pro_Price"),rs.getString("Pro_Quantity"),rs.getString("Pro_Supplier_id"));
                proList.add(update_del_insert_products);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return proList;
    }

    //display data in jtable 
    public void show_suppliers_in_Jtable(){
        ArrayList<Update_del_insert_products> list= getuserList();
        DefaultTableModel model =(DefaultTableModel)jTable_Products.getModel();
        Object[] row =new Object[5];
        for(int i =0;i< list.size();i++)
        {
            row[0] = list.get(i).getpro_Id();
            row[1] = list.get(i).getpro_Name();
            row[2] = list.get(i).getpro_Price();
            row[3] = list.get(i).getpro_Quantity();
            row[4] = list.get(i).getpro_Supplier_id();

            model.addRow(row);
        }
    }

    //execute the sql query REFRESH JTABLE 
    public void  executeSQLQuery (String query,String message) {
        Connection con =getConnection();
        Statement st;
        try{
            st =con.createStatement();
            if((st.executeUpdate(query))==1)
            {
                //refresh jtable data
                DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable_Products.getModel();
                model.setRowCount(0);
                show_Products_in_Jtable();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data "+message+" Succefully");
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Not "+message+ "Error");
            }

        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Pro_Name = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Pro_Price = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Pro_Quantity = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Pro_Supplier_id = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable_Products = new javax.swing.JTable();
        Back = new javax.swing.JButton();
        AddProduct = new javax.swing.JButton();
        UptadeProduct = new javax.swing.JButton();
        DeleteProduct = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Pro_Id = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Products");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Name ");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Price");

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Quantity");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Supplier_id");

        Pro_Supplier_id.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Pro_Supplier_idActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTable_Products.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Name ", "Price", "Quantity", "Supplier_id"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable_Products);

        Back.setText("Back");
        Back.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BackActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        AddProduct.setText("Add");
        AddProduct.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                AddProductActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        UptadeProduct.setText("Update");
        UptadeProduct.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                UptadeProductActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        DeleteProduct.setText("Delete");
        DeleteProduct.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                DeleteProductActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Id");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(187, 187, 187)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(Pro_Name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(Pro_Price, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 378, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 630, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(Back)))
                    .addGap(24, 24, 24))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(325, 325, 325)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(56, 56, 56)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 80, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(AddProduct, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3)))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(85, 85, 85)
                                    .addComponent(UptadeProduct, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(97, 97, 97)
                                    .addComponent(DeleteProduct, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                        .addComponent(Pro_Id, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(Pro_Supplier_id, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addComponent(Pro_Quantity, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                    .addGap(210, 210, 210)))))
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(Pro_Name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(Pro_Price, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                    .addComponent(Pro_Quantity, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel6)))
                            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(Pro_Supplier_id, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3))
                            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                .addComponent(Pro_Id, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(0, 34, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 234, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 83, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(AddProduct, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(DeleteProduct, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(UptadeProduct, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                    .addComponent(Back)
                    .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void BackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Pback();
    }

    private void Pro_Supplier_idActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void AddProductActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String query="INSERT INTO Products(Pro_Id ,Pro_Name,Pro_Price,Pro_Quantity,Pro_Supplier_id)VALUES ('"+Pro_Id.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Name.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Price.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Quantity.getText()+" ','"+Pro_Supplier_id.getText()+" ') ";
        executeSQLQuery(query,"Inserted");
        // KATAXORI STON PINAKA Suppliers ta stoixeia  meso ths update_del_insert  kai ta emfanizei sto text stis antoistixes theseis  
    }

    private void UptadeProductActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String query ="UPDATE  Products SET Pro_Name ='"+Pro_Id.getText()+" ' ,'"+Pro_Name.getText()+" ' ,Pro_Price = '"+Pro_Price.getText()+" ' ,Pro_Quantity = '"+Pro_Quantity.getText()+" ' ,Pro_Supplier_id = '"+Pro_Supplier_id.getText()+" ') ";
        executeSQLQuery(query,"Updated");
        // ananeonei  STON PINAKA Suppliers ta stoixeia  meso ths update_del_insert 
    }

    private void DeleteProductActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String query ="DELETE FROM Products WHERE Pro_Id ="+Pro_Id.getText();
        // NA BALO NA KANEI ELENXO DIAGRAFEIS 
        executeSQLQuery(query,"Deleted");
    }
    private void jtable_ProductsMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        // Display selected Row In JtextFields ston pinaka mas 
        int i =jTable_Products.getSelectedRow();
        TableModel model =jTable_Products.getModel();
        Pro_Id.setText((String) model.getValueAt(i,0));
        Pro_Name.setText(model.getValueAt(i,1).toString());
        Pro_Price.setText(model.getValueAt(i,2).toString());
        Pro_Quantity.setText(model.getValueAt(i,3).toString());
        Pro_Supplier_id.setText(model.getValueAt(i,4).toString());
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Products.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Products.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Products.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Products.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Products().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton AddProduct;
    private javax.swing.JButton Back;
    private javax.swing.JButton DeleteProduct;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Pro_Id;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Pro_Name;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Pro_Price;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Pro_Quantity;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Pro_Supplier_id;
    private javax.swing.JButton UptadeProduct;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable_Products;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private void Pback() {
        Console c=new Console ();
        c.setVisible(true);
        WindowEvent winClosing = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClosing);
    }

    private void show_Products_in_Jtable() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private static class Arraylist<T> {
        public Arraylist() {
        }
    }
}
```

I cant run it and keep saying this i have no idea how to fix this cause iam new in java any help ? ty

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at mylogin.Products.show_Products_in_Jtable(Products.java:436)
    at mylogin.Products.<init>(Products.java:31)
    at mylogin.Products$6.run(Products.java:398)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: You throws the excpetion: private void show_Products_in_Jtable() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }. Implement it in the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this exception because of this:

```
private void show_Products_in_Jtable() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
```

You call this method explicitly in the constructor of `Products` that is why you get this exception, implement this method properly and you won't have this issue anymore.

Comment: ok ty !! But i really dont know how to fix it . Any example  what i have to do ?